# Use specific CacheProvider for a Dynamic Data Store

Tags: episerver

We have some problems due to caching in EPiServer dynamic data stores, as different servers keep old data around. We need to ensure that when we fetch and save some items to/from the database, these items are *not* cached, but retrieved and saved directly from/to the database.

The problem for us is: how do we configure this on a per-store basis? When following [the directions on EpiServer for configuring caching for stores](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Developers-Guide/Episerver-Framework/7/Dynamic-Data-Store/Dynamic-Data-Store/#Configuration) (and [here](http://world.episerver.com/documentation/items/developers-guide/episerver-cms/7/configuration/configuring-episerverdatastore-section/)), it seems to apply to *all* stores, not just one.

We would like to set a NullCacheProvider for *a* store, *not all* stores.

[This example](http://world.episerver.com/blogs/Johan-Bjornfot/Dates1/2010/1/Dynamic-Data-Store-caching--The-internals/) shows how to disable the cache using code, but it sets the static `CacheProvider.Instance`, which I would assume is used by *all* episerver stores.

Comment: If you can't solve this using the `CacheProvider.Instance.ClearStore(storeName: "whatever")` I assume this is the case where you are better of with Unity.

Comment: As in dependency injecting the right provider? Well, the problem is that I cannot find any constructor accepting a cache provider. Hoping I understood you.

Comment: Thought ClearStore only removed the mappings, not the cache?